# 3G connectivity lost; reboot required to restore it

Tags: connection-issues, data-connection

Similar to this question, but slightly different/worse:
[Restart data connection when stalled?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30570/restart-data-connection-when-stalled)

Every so often – usually every day – I'll lose data connectivity (the icon in the status bar goes grey). Sometimes I can restore it simply by toggling the data connection on and off, but more often this doesn't work and nothing short of a reboot will actually restore it.

I can live with having to enable/disable it every now and then, but having to reboot my phone is a real inconvenience (especially as it's encrypted and requires a password to boot).

Is this a hardware, software, or network issue, and is there anything I can do to fix it? I'm running stock 4.1.2 on a Nexus S.

Comment: It might be a carrier problem, or just a connection issue. Try toggling airplane mode on/off to see if that fixes the problem. This will cause your phone to disconnect from your mobile network and then reconnect and start a new session. If you don't get a good answer here you should probably just report it to your carrier and have them look at it.